# sed prints out all data instead of substituted part which i want to extract

Tags: regex, sed

I am aware, that this problem has been asked in slightly different ways many times before. But I couldn't adapt those solutions.
I am having a file header.out with the following content:

```
// some text before this 
            :type = "Primary Grid: Tau Format" ;
            :deformation_timestep = 0. ;
            :deformation_alpha = 0. ;
            :deformation_dalpha = 0. ;
            :deformation_h = 0. ;
            :deformation_dh = 0. ;
            :deformation_step = 0 ;
            :adaptation_level = 0 ;
            :connectivity_check = 1 ;
            :volume_check = 1 ;
            :point_check = 1 ;
            :test_lib_check = 1 ;
            :periodic_pairs_check = 1 ;
            :is_balanced = 0 ;
            :preserve_piles = 0 ;
            :marker_1 = "WingMidTrailing" ;
            :marker_2 = "WingMidLower" ;
            :marker_3 = "WingMidUpper" ;
            :marker_4 = "WingSide" ;
            :marker_5 = "Farfield" ;
            :marker_6 = "SymmetryPlane" ;
            :marker_7 = "WingInnerLower" ;
            :marker_8 = "WingInnerUpper" ;
            :marker_9 = "WingInnerTrailing" ;
            :marker_10 = "WingOuterLower" ;
            :marker_11 = "WingOuterUpper" ;
            :marker_12 = "WingOuterTrailing" ;
 }
```

I need to extract the ID of the marker that belongs to the string "SymmetryPlane"
So in this case i want to have 6 as the output. All tries using sed and regular expressions failed.
What i have tried is:

```
sed 's/.*marker_\(.*\) = "SymmetryPlane.*/\1/' header.out
```

But this only gives me

```
            :type = "Primary Grid: Tau Format" ;
            :deformation_timestep = 0. ;
            :deformation_alpha = 0. ;
            :deformation_dalpha = 0. ;
            :deformation_h = 0. ;
            :deformation_dh = 0. ;
            :deformation_step = 0 ;
            :adaptation_level = 0 ;
            :connectivity_check = 1 ;
            :volume_check = 1 ;
            :point_check = 1 ;
            :test_lib_check = 1 ;
            :periodic_pairs_check = 1 ;
            :is_balanced = 0 ;
            :preserve_piles = 0 ;
            :marker_1 = "WingMidTrailing" ;
            :marker_2 = "WingMidLower" ;
            :marker_3 = "WingMidUpper" ;
            :marker_4 = "WingSide" ;
            :marker_5 = "Farfield" ;
6
            :marker_7 = "WingInnerLower" ;
            :marker_8 = "WingInnerUpper" ;
            :marker_9 = "WingInnerTrailing" ;
            :marker_10 = "WingOuterLower" ;
            :marker_11 = "WingOuterUpper" ;
            :marker_12 = "WingOuterTrailing" ;
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just suppress the output (`-n`) and print after substitution (`p`):

```
sed -n 's/.*marker_\(.*\) = "SymmetryPlane.*/\1/p' header.out
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
As a new member, do you know why I got downvoted? Not sure what i should have done different.

Comment: You can change the title to something like: `sed prints out all data instead of substituted part` to be more helpful to people with similar problems.

Comment: Okay I guess that's a good idea. Thanks